# Mongoose - how to skip finding a specific document?

Tags: express, mongoose

How to I exclude certain documents from the search result?

```
Stream.findOne({
    _id: query.id
}, function(err, stream) {

    var output = {};
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error retrieving streams: " + err);
    }

    if (!stream) {
        console.log("No stream found");
    }

    if (stream) {
        console.log("Stream found");
    }
});
```

For instance I want `findOne` to skip looking for `_id` of `1234`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try doing this using `MongoDB Logical Query operators.`

For more information on logical operators , see [MongoDB documentation for Logical Query Operators.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and)

```
Stream.findOne({ $and : [ {_id: query.id } ,{ _id:{ $ne : "1234"} } ] 
}, function(err, stream) {

    var output = {};
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error retrieving streams: " + err);
    }

    if (!stream) {
        console.log("No stream found");
    }

    if (stream) {
        console.log("Stream found");
    }
});
```